# How to dynamically hide a div in IE10+?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a button with position: absolute that is displayed perfectly centered between two sections in latest Chrome and Firefox. However, in Internet Explorer 11 the button is moved to the left of the page and only displays half, which destroys the layout.

You can find a [JS Bin here](http://jsbin.com/todufuma/4/watch?html,css,js).

[image]

**CSS/LESS:**

```
.button {
   z-index: 150;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 110px 0 0 -125px;
   height: 54px;
   width: 250px;
   letter-spacing: 3px;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

In order to simply hide the button in Internet Explorer, I used the following conditional comment:

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <style>#slogan .button {display: none;}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Unfortunately, this only works in older versions of IE. [Conditional comments have been depreciated from IE 10 upwards.](http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/)

Is there a work around?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the problem, rather than hiding it? IE11 is pretty solid/standards-compliant.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: I hate IE as much as the next web dev, but I gotta agree with Tim. Any chance you could share a bit more code or even a codepen/fiddle to see if there's an issue?

Comment: ...I'm wondering about why position:absolute. I don't see any positioning. What about more css and the html? It's like trying to draw a home plan just looking throw a keyhole.

Comment: Using

position: absolute;
implies that your HTML is not organised well. Maybe you should share your HTML so we can make suggestions

Comment: @Tim Medora: Here is a JS Bin http://jsbin.com/todufuma/4/watch?html,css,js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really best to fix the styles so they work in all browsers. As Tim Medora and others have pointed out IE10+ are much more standards compliant these days.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Section 1 -->
<div id="section1" class="container-fluid text-center">

  <div class="container">
  ... moved the form from here ...
  </div>

  <!--
   - Move this form from the ".container" to "#section1".
   - Add the .learn-more-container class to the form.
  -->
  <form class="learn-more-container" action="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary hidden-xs learn-more-btn">BUTTON</button>
    </form>
</div><!-- /. Section 1 -->
```

**CSS:**

Then update your `#section1` css to this:

```
#section1 .learn-more-container {
    z-index: 150;  
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
}

#section1 .learn-more-btn {
    height: 54px;
    width: 250px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

That will fix your button to work in all browsers - in fact these changes work on IE8+.

Here's an updated jsbin showing the changes: http://jsbin.com/todufuma/7/edit

Answer (score 6):

I finally found a straightforward, simple solution using jQuery to detect Internet Explorer including latest version 11:

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie|trident/i)) {
          alert('You are using the worst browser on this planet.');
          $('.button').hide();
        }
      });
 </script>
```

Comment: Good one. When I use hide() in IE11, it's not even hiding the div.

Answer (score 0):

Use the style.display method in JavaScript: [style.display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027051/how-to-dynamically-hide-a-div-in-ie10)

```
var el = document.getElementById("button");
    el.style.display = "none";
```

You can also get the browser type by getting the value of `navigator.userAgent`